# Create a Point from every two integers

Tags: java, oop

I must use Scanner to read a file of integers and create "n" number of points. Here is an example of a file:

```
4 110 115 112 112 140 145 130 190
3 125 125 130 150 110 110
```

The numbers 5 and 4 at the beginning represent the number of Point objects I need to create, and after that, every two integers must create form one Point. Here is an example of the output:

```
OUTPUT:
[(110, 115), (112, 112), (140, 145), (130, 190)]
[(125, 125), (130, 150), (110, 110)]
```

How can I possibly loop in every line, and choose to separate every two integers to form one Point object?

Comment: Google for "how to read lines in Java". Then google for "how to split a string in Java". Then, hopefully, you know about loops, otherwise google for "how to use loops in Java". In short: divide the problem into simpler tasks, do some research, and try something. The documentation, tutorials, etc. are freely available.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I mean I can read the file and loop through every line, but I couldn't find a way to split every two integers separately.

Comment: Can you please add more information?
(What you got so far, where do you want to ouput to [file/console/create object])

Comment: So, google for "how to split a string in Java". Then combine numbers in the result 2 by 2, using a loop.

Comment: `The numbers 5 and 4` should be `The numbers 4 and 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;

        //read line untill it's not null or empty
        while ((line = in.nextLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            //split line by regex \s (whiteSpace chars)
            String[] ints = line.split("\\s");
            //our array could be empty if there was just spaces in line
            if (ints.length == 0)
                return;

            //Think it's understandable
            int count = Integer.parseInt(ints[0]);
            Point[] points = new Point[count];

            //according to line structure, x and y of point number i would be
            // i * 2 + 1 and i * 2 + 2
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(ints[i * 2 + 1]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(ints[i * 2 + 2]);
                points[i] = new Point(x, y);
            }

            //To achieve output like yours, use Arrays.toString()
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
        }
    }
}
```

Point class:

```
public class Point{
int x, y;

public Point(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public String toString(){
    return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
    String text = "3 125 125 130 150 110 110";
    //First of all you have to split your text to get array of numbers
    String[] splitted_text = text.split(" ");
    //the first number of array represents the point count
    //so declare an array of points by this count
    Point[] points = new Point[Integer.parseInt(splitted_text[0])];

    //numbers in odd positions starting from 1 represent x
    //numbers in even positions starting from 2 represent x
    //so you can form points using numbers in even and odd positions
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i].x=Integer.parseInt(splitted_text[2*i + 1]);
        points[i].y=Integer.parseInt(splitted_text[2*i + 2]);            
    }
```

Comment: You could explain the code so that people can learn from it rather than just copy & paste it.